# Facebook and Twitter not showing on MVC 4 default Template

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

I saw lot of articles having **Face book** and **Twitter** handlers on **MVC 4 default template** with **visual studio 2012**.But in my template it doesn't. So what should I do for enable it by default ?

[image: **enter image description here**]

**UPDATE:** Actually I don't need to know about OAuth implementation.I just need to know whether default template having above mentioned kind of UI components for Facebook and Twitter (red color) ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to uncomment OAuth authentication for Facebook and Twitter in `App_Code/AuthConfig.cs` file. Once you do this you will need to register with Facebook your App to get the security key. Once you do that you should be able to use Facebook and/or Twitter as authentication services.

The AuthConfig.cs looks like this:

```
public static class AuthConfig
{
    public static void RegisterAuth()
    {
        // To let users of this site log in using their accounts from other sites such as Microsoft, Facebook, and Twitter,
        // you must update this site. For more information visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=252166

        //OAuthWebSecurity.RegisterMicrosoftClient(
        //    clientId: "",
        //    clientSecret: "");

        OAuthWebSecurity.RegisterTwitterClient(
            consumerKey: "",
            consumerSecret: "");

        OAuthWebSecurity.RegisterFacebookClient(
            appId: "",
            appSecret: "");

        //OAuthWebSecurity.RegisterGoogleClient();
    }
}
```

In addition to this, have a look at this CodeProject article that will guide throught the process of using OAuth in MVC 4: [Introduction to OAuth in ASP.NET MVC](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/577384/Introduction-to-OAuth-in-ASP-NET-MVC)

UPDATE: In case of your UPDATE, my answer would not quite be the solution.

Comment: You gave me a more information than what I expected.But My issue is MVC 4 default template having face book or twitter UI images as showing on my image (red color)?